# Python Scrapy, How to get second image on the page with scrapy?

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy

I only want to extract exact one image on every page that scrapy looking for. For example I want to extract http://eshop.erhanteknik.com.tr/photo/foto_w720_604e44853371a920a52b0a31a3548b8b.jpg from http://eshop.erhanteknik.com.tr/tos_svitavy/tos_svitavy/uc_ayakli_aynalar_t0803?DS7641935 page which scrapy looks first. With this code I am currently get whole images with .getall command but I cannot figure how can get specific image.

```
from scrapy.http import Request


class BooksSpider(Spider):
    name = 'books'
    allowed_domains = ['eshop.erhanteknik.com.tr']
    start_urls = ['http://eshop.erhanteknik.com.tr/urunlerimiz?categoryId=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
        for book in books:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_book)

        # process next page
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page_url)
        
    def parse_book(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        image_url = response.xpath('//img/@src').getall()
        yield {
            'title': title,
            'image_url': image_url,
        }
        pass
```

Comment: Use `.get()` if you want the first image

Comment: If the images are in the same location of the page, make the xpath more specific to that location.

Comment: Try looking for extra metadata on that image , perhaps, an `id`, or a class, or the parent id or class, so you will get that specific image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `src` of the images under the `slide` class.

```
image_url = response.css('.slide img::attr(src)').extract_first()
```

`extract_first()` will grab the first item of the list.
If you use `extract()`, you will get a list.